# Does consumer consume from replica partitions if multiple consumers running under same consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am writing a kafka consumer application. I have a topic with 4 partitions - 1 is leader and 3 are followers. Producer uses key to identify a partition to push a message.
If I write a consumer and run it on different nodes or start 4 instances of same consumer, how message consuming will happen ? Does all 4 instances will get same messages ?

1. What happens in the case of multiple consumer(same group) consuming a single topic?
2. Do they get same data?
3. How offset is managed? Is it separate for each consumer?

Comment: You can find information about a way how consumer work on official Kafka page: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What happens in the case of multiple consumer(same group) consuming a single topic?

   **Answer:** Producers send records to a particular partition based on the record’s key here. The default partitioner for Java uses a hash of the record’s key to choose the partition. When there are multiple consumers in same consumer group, each consumer gets different partition. So, in this case, only single consumer receives all the messages. When the consumer which is receiving messages goes down, group coordinator (one of the brokers in the cluster) triggers rebalance and then that partition is assigned to one of the available consumer.
2. Do they get same data?

   **Answer:** If consumer commits consumed messages to partition and goes down, so as stated above, rebalance occurs. The consumer who gets this partition, will not get messages. But if consumer goes down before committing its then the consumer who gets this partition, will get messages.
3. How offset is managed? Is it separate for each consumer?

   **Answer:** No, offset is not separate to each consumer. Partition never gets assigned to multiple consumers in same consumer group at a time. The consumer who gets partition assigned, gets offset as well by default.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you read at least first few chapters of confluent's definitive guide to kafka to get a priliminary understanding of how kafka works.

I've kept my answers brief. Please refer to the book for detailed explanation.

How offset is managed? Is it separate for each consumer?

Depends on the group id. Only one offset is managed for a group.

What happens in the case of multiple consumer(same group) consuming a single topic?
Consumers can be multiple - all can be identified by the same or different groups.
If 2 consumers belong to the same group, both will not get all messages.

Do they get same data?
No. Once a message is sent and a read is committed, the offset is incremented for that group. So a different consumer with the same group will not receive that message.

Hope that helps :)